# Properties of powerfully embedded subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82387641.pdf) article and I have some doubts about the proof of **Theorem 1.1** (page 3).

**(1)** In the seconde paragraph:

> "... let $L \triangleleft G$ be such that...",

why such $L$ exists and why

> "$L \supset [K,G,G]$"?

---

**(2)** In the thrid paragraph:

> "... This implies  that $\mho_{1}([N,G]) = [\mho_{1}(N),G]$...",

I cannot see the implication.

---

Thanks for the advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $M$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of a finite $p$-group $G$, then $[G,M] < M$, $[G,M]$ is normal in $G$, and $G$ centralizes $G/[G,M]$ so, if we choose $L$ with $[G,M] \le L < M$ with $|L:M|=p$ then $L$ is normal in $G$ and $[M,G] \le L$. For Question (1) apply this with $M = [K,G]$.

For (2), by using the commutator identity $[ab,c] = [a,c][[a,c],b][b,c]$ (here $[a,b] = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$) and $[N,G] \le Z_2(G)$, we get (for $n \in N$, $g \in G$)
$$[n^p,g] = [n,g]^p[[n,g],g]^{p(p-1)/2} = [n,g]^p[[n,g]^{p(p-1)/2},g]$$
from which the result follows (we are assuming that $p$ is odd).

Comment: Thank you, Derek. I read the reference, but it uses other definitions and results about other classes of groups (they are not part of the topics of my course) and I think that (2) is a particular case of this reference. I even tried to adapt the proof, but it does not seem to work without using such definitions.

Comment: I have now written a sketch proof of (2).